# Is there any way to print out a dictionary consisted of unicode strings by converting them to other coding?

Tags: python, dictionary, python-unicode

I was writing a program and stuck a little bit. I am trying to add key and and a value to dict. But all my variables are in Unicode. If I convert them to a string by encoding them to utf-8, I get the same answer.

```
   #! /usr/bin/env python
   # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
   name = u'\u041d\u0435\u0433\u0440\u043e\u043d\u0438'
   surname = u'\u041b\u043e\u043d\u0434\u043e\u043d\u0441\u043a\u0438\u0439'
   info = {}
   info[name] = surname
```

So If I am trying to print out name:

```
    print(name) --> it prints the right answer
```

And if I am trying to print out dict info:

```
    print(info) --> prints out unicode chars
```

P.S. The output should be written in Russian Language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are two ways.

```
name = u'\u041d\u0435\u0433\u0440\u043e\u043d\u0438'
surname = u'\u041b\u043e\u043d\u0434\u043e\u043d\u0441\u043a\u0438\u0439'
info = {}
info[name] = surname

#One way
{print(info[k]) for k in info}

#Another way
print(info[name].encode("unicode-escape").decode("unicode-escape"))
```

Answer (score 3):

Upgrade to Python 3....

```py
>>> print(name)
Негрони
>>> print(info)
{'Негрони': 'Лондонский'}
```

Depending on your project of course, but I would highly recommend it.
Especially considering [Sunsetting Python 2](https://www.python.org/doc/sunset-python-2/)